# is it possible to setup Google Site Search or something similar on a html page with frames

Tags: search, full-text-search

I have a site similar to: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/

I was looking at using Google site search or something like that... I have documentation for something thats very similar and gotta make it searchable.  Ultimately the issue is frames...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to use Google site search with frames as you delegate the control to google. They do not know that you want your results to be displayed in another frame.

You have to understand that the ruby docs is not searchable. The site you link to is static and gets generated with a script on every release of Ruby. There is no textfield to enter a query.

Try generating some similar output with a script or use a standard search engine like http://sphinxsearch.com/ with some custom code (e.g. Ruby, Python, ASP or PHP).

Comment: I know that the Rubydocs aren't searchable.  I have a docs page thats pretty similar so I am trying to setup a search for that.  Starting to believe its not possible.